# Arduino Uno Keyboard code

Tags: keyboard, arduino

I have a student who wants to make a glove that acts as a keyboard. His idea is very similar to the old Nintendo Power Glove. By sewing or gluing foil "contacts" onto the finger tips he can create a series of switches aligned to specific keyboard keys.

I've already gone through the process of flashing the Arduino Uno's firmware to a version that will support keyboard commands. The next step is figuring out how to code the project. We experimented with a random character command and saw it work via the Arduino IDE Serial Monitor. Now we want to control specific keys using the appropriate decimal code.

This is where we have run into an issue. When we try what we think are the correct decimal codes, we are getting incorrect keyboard presses. This is being done on a laptop, is there a separate keyboard decimal code for laptop keyboards compared to standard usb keyboards?

Does anyone have any advice or experience with this?

Sorry if my question is too ambiguous, please let me know if you need more info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For keyboard input, I honestly recommend you using/buying an Arduino Micro or something similar as they support the inbuilt keyboard library, which is easy to use and hard to go wrong.

You sure you haven't checked these codes?
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/KeyboardModifiers
and...
http://www.asciitable.com

If they don't work, I suggest trial and error until you reach a letter and then try to increment the used decimal code one by one and see if the output changes in a sequential and recognisable manner/pattern. If it doesn't, then the code or your hack on the Arduino Uno may be at fault.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, and sorry for my delayed response. We were able to get the Serial Monitor to show what key was being pressed, but in order to control anything it seems that we would need a Leonardo or better.

Comment: I believe it is possible to modify the second chip on the arduino Uno (as that is the chip used in the Leonardo to allow HID keyboard and mouse inputs) but for all the trouble, may as well buy an actual Leonardo. For the sake of being compact, go for the arduino micro and get a breadboard or some female jumper wires.